# Formula to get all matching values and return all occurrences of match in order based on 1st occurrence of a value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This one is interesting and I am not even sure if it can be done with a formula. I can do it with a macro but I want a formula for this one.

I have 2 sets of data. The 1st set contains some dates and a true/false field and an ID number. The 2nd set of data contains some dates and ID number and a blank column. Now I need to find the 1st occurrence of an ID number in the 2nd dataset and then based on that check the 1st dataset for matching numbers and then check if value is false in the 3rd column. If that value is false return date from 2nd column.

Now I can go this on my own with a vlookup if I only wanted the 1st occurrence but I need to get all matches. The dates in the 2nd column can be ignored they are not part of the formula.

Here is an example of what the data should look like after applying the formula. I need the false dates to be returned. I know I can build this as a function but I really need to do a formula if possible.

Update:

I did find JOINTEXT() however that does not work in excel 2013 :| so that is out of the question.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to understand. It concludes that you want to filter rows with value "false". Why not use filter and copy rows to another place?

Comment: That is a manual effort. No formula I am aware of can filter rows like that. This data set is very small example. The original is massive

Comment: Sounds more like a need for some sort of SQL..

Comment: @AlexR If I was going to go that far I would just write a VBA script. I know I can do this with a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and `AGGREGATE` combination:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/((G2=A:A)*(0=--(C:C))),COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2))),"")
```

In my example in column `C` are boolean values. If you have text there then change part of formula `(0=--(C:C))` to `("FALSE"=C:C)`

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly. Only thing is it is a little be hard on my excel file. Things slowed way down. I will have to set the column of formulas to the value but does what I need. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to change full column references with appropriate ranges in formula. It might help.

Comment: Ya we actually had it references our table columns as the data is in tables and not just a basic excel page. Works much faster now. Only problem is we had to manually set column B as B1:B300 due to the index being off by 2 if we referenced the actually table column but still works for our needs ty.